# debug c# bugged very basic calculator

Tags: c#, debugging

this code isn't working, can somebody help me with this?

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
   var p = '+';
   var m = '-';
   int a = Console.Read();
   var s = Console.Read();
   int b = Console.Read();
   if (s == p)
   {
      int sum = a + b;
      Console.WriteLine(sum);
   }
   else if (s == m)
   {
      if (a < b)
      {
         Console.WriteLine("!ERROR!");
      }
      else
      {
         int sum = a - b;
         Console.WriteLine(sum);
      }
   }
   else
   {
      Console.WriteLine("!ERROR!");
   }
}
```

When i input for example 5  +  5, it spontaneously adds another
5  + ,
so that it will output "!ERROR!".
If somebody can help me out with this please.

Comment: Debug it, tell us what is wrong, then you have already solved your own problem

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Note that `Console.Read` reads 1 character and returns the unicode code point for it, which for `'0'` is 48. Note that `Console.Read` does **not** read the next number, so if you input `10+5`, it will return the unicode code point of the `1` which is 49, not the number 10. I fear that you might need to rethink your strategy on this calculator implementation and come up with a better approach. My advice would be to write a method that takes the whole string and evaluates it, this should also make it easier to write tests for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `Console.Read()` then you have to input all characters in one line and then press enter to get result:
[image]

[`Console.Read()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.read?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Console_Read) reads a single character. 
In your case when you enter "5", you're supplying the character '5', whose ASCII value is 53, and then again "5". The sum of these is 106!

[image]

So, `Console.Read()` returns the index of the Unicode codepoint that you typed. 
You can create an additional method to convert it to number like:

```
public static int CharToInt(int c)
{
    if (c < '0' || c > '9')
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("The character should be a number");
    }

    return c - '0';
}
```

and use it like:

```
 int a = CharToInt(Console.Read());
 var s = Console.Read();
 int b = CharToInt(Console.Read());
```

Comment: ["`Console.Read()` Reads the next character from the standard input stream.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.read?view=netframework-4.7.2) By "character" they mean `Char` value converted to Int32. ["`Char` Represents a character as a UTF-16 code unit."](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char?view=netframework-4.7.2) UTF-16 is the character encoding of the Unicode character set used by .NET (and others). It takes one or two UTF-16 code units to encode a Unicode codepoint. So "returns the index of the Unicode codepoint that you typed" isn't quite right